# Padding/Margin appearing where there shouldn't be any in a 3 column layout

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I am trying to create a 3 column layout for a website design that contains an image at the top of each column followed by a h3 then some text. I have done this in the html but when I get to the CSS there are padding/margin coming from somewhere even when I set them both to 0.

Also for some reason the columns aren't aligned vertically correctly?

**HTML:**

```
<h3>Why You Should Choose Us For Financing Options.</h3>
<div class="card">
  <img src="Heart.png" alt="Heart">
  <h5>Lowest Industry Rates</h5>
  <p>We take pride in our rates being the lowest in the industry!</p>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <img src="Coin.png" alt="Coin">
  <h5>Our Funding Is Fast</h5>
  <p>After completing our form, you can expect to receive your funding within 48 hours!</p>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <img src="File.png" alt="File">
  <h5>We're Quick And Easy</h5>
  <p>The form is easy to understand and can be completed in minutes!</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
header h3 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat Light', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #FFF;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 260px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

Image of desired outcome: https://i.gyazo.com/f4a2ef3a9680a1ee79eaafd889d368b7.png

Current outcome:
https://i.gyazo.com/fd2eafc6a980527a07811e409a9262bd.png

Comment: provide a codepen or jsfiddle or something so we can reproduce the issue...

Comment: I have tried it on JSFiddle but the issue doesn't seem to appear on there. So I am thinking it is to do with the images

Comment: Well, then the issue may not be the code at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about try this:

HTML:

```
<h3>Why You Should Choose Us For Financing Options.</h3>
<div id="fc">
    <div class="card">
        <img src="Heart.png" alt="Heart">
        <h5>Lowest Industry Rates</h5>
        <p>We take pride in our rates being the lowest in the industry!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <img src="Coin.png" alt="Coin">
        <h5>Our Funding Is Fast</h5>
        <p>After completing our form, you can expect to receive your funding within 48 hours!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <img src="File.png" alt="File">
        <h5>We're Quick And Easy</h5>
        <p>The form is easy to understand and can be completed in minutes!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
header h3 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat Light', sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 60px;
}

#fc {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.card {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 260px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
```

Comment: I worked out that it is the amount of text I have that causes the vertical position error, would the above still work in that case?

Comment: Yes a flex-box where the content is justified as the space-between, spaces the individual cards in the container to have space in-between (as the property name suggests) and gives them the height of the container. So that should fix your issue.